# Query regarding without Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate) I see a crash

Tags: javascript, v8

I have a DLL with `init`, `deinit`, `start`, `stop`, methodcall methods. There is only one isolate scope. In `init`, I register the platform

```
platformZ = platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
V8::InitializePlatform(platformZ.get());
V8::Initialize();
```

In start I create the isolate

```
// Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
// Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
// ..
Local<Context> context = Context::New(isolate, NULL, global);
Context::Scope context_scope(context);
```

In methodCall, I find the instance of MyClass and call myMethod in it. If I don't call isolate_scope, the is a crash after making around 100 calls to myMethod, I get an exception   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000. When I call isolate_scope, the exception does not happen.

```
Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);    
// Go into the existing scope     
HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
```

I don't exit the scope by any other instructor. Could someone please tell me **why isolate_scope** makes it work?. In all the samples, isolate_scope is not used in method calls.   My understanding is that isolate_scope is not needed since there is no other scope.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question right, it sounds like there's a misunderstanding about what a "scope" object is: its lifetime (per C++ semantics) is meaningful, and this lifetime ends at the end of the block in which the object was created. So if you have two different functions, they definitely each need their own scope. You didn't post your complete code so I can only guess about its structure, probably it's roughly like:

```
void Start(...) {
  Isolate::Scope scope1(isolate);
  /* stuff ... */
}  // "scope1" dies here!

void MethodCall(...) {
  Isolate::Scope scope2(isolate);
  /* stuff ... */
}  // "scope2" dies here!

int main(...) {
  Start(...);
  // No active scope at this point, "scope1" has died!
  MethodCall(...);  // <-- absolutely needs to create its own scope
}
```

To demonstrate the effect, one can even create a simpler (and V8-independent) example:

```
#include <iostream>
class Scope {
 public:
  explicit Scope(std::string name) : name_(name) { 
    std::cout << "Scope " << name_ << " created\n";
  }
  ~Scope() {
    std::cout << "Scope " << name_ << " destroyed\n";
  }
 private:
  std::string name_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Entering main...\n";
  {
    Scope s1("scope1");
    std::cout << "We have a scope\n";
  }  // s1 dies here!
  std::cout << "No active scope at this point\n";
  {
    Scope s2("scope2");
    std::cout << "A new scope!\n";
  }  // s2 dies here!
  std::cout << "All scopes gone, quitting now\n";
  return 0;
}
```

That said, using `v8::Isolate::Scope` is optional. It's just a convenience wrapper around `v8::Isolate::Enter()` and `v8::Isolate::Exit()`. You can call those functions manually if you require/prefer semantics that don't conveniently map to scope lifetimes.

Comment: I have a DLL. The structure you mentioned is very similar to my code except that MethodCall is outside and is a DLL method. I do have HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);. But If I don't use isolate_scope I run into error. The google sample https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/6.8/samples/process.cc also does not have isolate_scope. I do need both Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
// Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
HandleScope handle_scope(isolate); and then it works. Please note I have kept isolate pointer in Global C++ memory.

Comment: @PankajChhabra Look closer: that example you linked does have an `Isolate::Scope isolate_scope` in line 717, whose lifetime covers the entire program execution. A `HandleScope` is something else, and you need one if you want to create handles.

Answer (score 0):

As [jmrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6036428/jmrk) said I think in the previous answer, the reason is the destruction of the `isolate_scope` instance at the end of the method.

You can use the `new` keyword to create a new instance as below:

```
auto isolate_scope = new v8::Isolate::Scope(isolate);
```

With this code, `isolate_scope` won't destruct at the end of the method.

Comment: That's a memory leak, so I'd call that a bad idea. Better not to use a scope at all instead.

Comment: You are right if you don't destroy it yourself; That's a memory leak. But you can destroy the instance when you want.